How to use expo go in a bare react native app?
I have a bare react native app where I also followed the steps from the expo documentation to be able to use expo modules in the app, I was wondering if it is possible for me to use expo go in a bare react native app so I can test the app on my IOS device as well as on Android emulator.
possible for me to use expo go in a bare react native app so I can test the app on my IOS device as well as on Android emulator.

You cannot use Expo Go with a bare react native app.
The bare react native app could have dependencies to native modules which were not available in Expo Go.
